# variavel php que guarda codigo html

Tags: php, html, html5, variáveis

Faz 2-3 anos que não uso php, ate aprendi sobre, mas recentemente fui olhar alguns códigos para realizar algumas modificações em um site e estou tendo uma grande dificuldade, a primeira é essa, tem uma pagina em php que faz a criação de um menu em html e logo dps desse menu tem um código php com uma variável, e ela simplesmente faz implementa todo o resto do conteúdo do site, se eu apaga-la fica só o menu no site. Queria saber o qual o nome disso, como se faz isso, e se possível algum site/vídeo para eu estudar sobre. Obgd!

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;">
    <div class="container">

      <a class="navbar-brand display-25" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><?php echo $this->settings->site_name; ?></a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="drop-menu btn dropdown-toggle"
          type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="f-size-18"><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i> Menu2</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url('/login'); ?>">SubMenu1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url('/login'); ?>">SubMenu2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url('/login'); ?>">SubMenu3</a>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="drop-menu btn dropdown-toggle"
          type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="f-size-18"><i class="fab fa-bitcoin"></i> Menu1</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url('/login'); ?>">SubMenu1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url('/login'); ?>">SubMenu2</a>
       </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0 f-size-18">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('/login'); ?>">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('/user/register'); ?>">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

`<!-- <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('message')) : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ($this->session->flashdata('error')) : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif (validation_errors()) : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ($this->error) : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <?php echo $this->error; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> -->

    <?php // Main content ?>
    <?php echo $content; ?> <code>`

A variável PHP a qual me refiro esta no fim deste código ("$content;").

Comment: Olá! Primeiro, você tem que por o código para que possamos lhe ajudar. A principio, o código da página "que faz a criação de um menu em html e logo dps desse menu tem um código php com uma variável". Edite sua questão e adicione o código dela para que possamos ver. Saudações.

Comment: Ok, vou colocar, vlw!

Comment: Bem. Provável estar usando um framework. Yii Framework ou outro. Um framework que usa MVC (Model-view-controller, em português modelo-vista-controlador). Esse `<?php echo $content; ?>` está na View e os dados são trabalhados e manipulado em conjunto com o Model e o Controller. Veja aqui, um caso onde a informação vem do C (Controller) e depois os dados capturados na V (View): https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html 
Veja : `$data['title'] = "My Real Title";` está no Controller e depois na View você chama `<title><?php echo $title;?></title>`

Comment: Este site usa esse framework mesmo, codeigniter, mas não conseguir entender ele. Como eu sei qual é o Controller q se encontra esta minha variável? Não tem nenhuma referência. O codigo da pagina é basicamente o q mostro acima

Comment: Procure na pasta Controller `application/controllers/`, pode ser outro caminho. Veja o nome do seu arquivo de visualização e encontre o controle baseado no nome da view.

Comment: Consegui encontrar o Controller, Obrigado! .. Agora é estudar mais para entender tudo isso kkk

Comment: Eu ia adicionar uma resposta sobre o parão MVC com o básico dentro da sua dúvida explicando como imprimir um `content` na View, usando MVC. Mas a questão foi fechada. Pena

Comment: Seria uma boa para quem tem o mesmo problema ... Uma pena msm